# how to make an integer into decimal format in vb

Tags: vb.net

I am doing a vb calculator, and I have two text boxes, one is for integer, the other is for decimal part. when it input in the decimal part text box, it need to output as integer.

```
for example: i text 9998 into decimal part text box should actually be 0.9998.  
so when i am doing a addition, i need to convert 98 to 0.98 to do the calculation
```

I couldn't figure it out, could someone help me?

Comment: Your question is unclear because at the end you state "..need to output as integer", whereas your title states that you want to convert an integer into decimal. Anyway, to convert 98 to 0.98 you would divide by 100. So perhaps you should clarify. For example, what is typed in the decimal part? And where does the addition come into play?

Comment: but if the integer i enter in the decimal part text box is 9999, then divided by 100 is 99.99 not 0.9999

Comment: Well the content of a TextBox is Text, so you could just add "0." at the front of it, according to the description in your comment.

Comment: i just don't know how to add it, if only add it in the text box later in calculation will still be 9999 not 0.9999

Answer (score 1):

Add the `.` to the string then convert it.

```
Private Function ToDecimalFromString(str As String) As Decimal
  Dim temp As String = String.Format("{0}{1}", ".", str)
  Dim dec As Decimal
  Decimal.TryParse(temp, dec)
  Return dec
End Function
```

Comment: Why `String.Format("{0}{1}", ".", str)` rather than just `String.Format(".{0}", str)`?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of the answer you would really like one of these two statements should do nicely:

```
    Dim Answer As Double = CTYPE(Textbox1.Text & "." & Textbox2.Text, Double)
```

or

```
    Dim Answer As Decimal = CTYPE(Textbox1.Text & "." & Textbox2.Text, Decimal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add "0." in front of text:

```
Dim assd As String = "9998"
dim ans as string

ans = "0." & assd
```